# Spring Data & Couchbase - finding documents that don't have a certain field

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase, sql++

In my Spring Boot app I have a couchbase bucket that holds the documents.

I CRUD the bucket with an interface that extends `CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository`.

I'm trying create a query that selects all documents that **Doesn't have certain field**.

So assuming we have these documents and we like to find the ones that don't have "color":

```
{
 "type":"Cat"
 "name":"Oscar",
 "color":"red"
}

{
 "type":"Cat"
 "name":"Polly"
}
```

I tried creating several methods in my interface:

```
public interface PetRepository<Pet, S> extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<Pet, String> {

List<Pet> findAllByTypeAndColorNull(String type);

List<Pet> findAllByTypeAndColorIsNull(String type);

List<Pet> findAllByTypeAndColorFalse(String type);
```

But all of them return empty list and not the expected document(s).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this field simply does not exist in your document, so the correct approach is to use the **MISSING** keyword:
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/comparisonops.html

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where #{#n1ql.filter} and companyId = $1 and (yourAtrribute IS NULL OR yourAtrribute IS MISSING )")
List<Checklist> listCheckCompanyId(String companyId);
```